# Style only the first match and the last match

Tags: css

How to target only the first and the last match of a selector in CSS?

**Example** (This is only an example, general solution needed) to illustrate my requirement:

```
<style>
    main>article p:first { /* to select the first p anywhere under article */ }
    main>article p:last { /* to select the last p anywhere under article  */ }
</style>
<main>
    <article>
        <section>
            <p>SHOULD be selected as first element</p>
            <p>SHOULD NOT be selected</p>
        </section>
        <ul>
            <li><p>SHOULD NOT be selected</p></li>
            <li><p>SHOULD NOT be selected</p></li>
        </ul>
        <p>SHOULD be selected as last element</p>
    </article>
</main>
```

The DOM under `<article>` might have `<p>` as children. `<p>`s (including the first and the last ones) are not required to be direct children of `<article>` though and can have any set of parents. Are there any not-necessarily-elegant CSS rule to select only the first and the last `<p>`?

JavaScript as indicated by tags of this question is not allowed, but for means of demonstration purposes… following code does exactly what I want to achieve:

```
var els   = document.querySelectorAll('main>article p'),
    first = els[0],
    last  = els[els.length - 1];
```

Now what I've already tried using and what did not work out for me:

- any selector combination with `:first-child`, `:last-child`

  - There's no guarantee of any structure which one could use to make a fail-proof selector which would select only the first and the last `p` which is a (not-necessarily-direct) chilren of `<article>`.
- any selector combination with `:first-of-type`, `:last-of-type`

  - Because this would also select first/last `article *>p`
  - In particular I've tried `main>article p:first-of-type` and `main>article p:first-of-type`.
- overriding with `~` and/or `+`

**EDITS**

1. The DOM will not necessarily will be the same as given in example – it's just an example after all.
2. Both first and last `<p>` is a children of article, but not always a direct children. That means there may be other elements between thne first/last `<p>` and parent `<article>`.
3. Just remembered jQuery. `$('main>article p:first')` and `$('main>article p:last')` from jQuery would do exactly what I want, but I'm restricted to CSS.

Comment: What selector combinations did you try with `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type`?

Comment: Is this [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crazyrohila/BXJWR/) you were trying to achieve ? BTW you didn't close <section> tag.

Comment: What browsers are you using as first-of-type and last-of-type should get you what you need.

Comment: tried with closing the section tag correctly? `</section>`

Comment: Holy hell... Somehow it seems that it's only recognizing that article have only one child, don't know why...

Comment: @crazyrohila yes it is, however last `<p>` will not necessarily will be a bare `article>p` and first `<p>` not necessarily `article>section>p`.

Comment: @Yenn, thanks I made a mistake in question. Edit was made.

Comment: @robertc I've tried `main>article p:first-of-type` and it selected way more than single p. (see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HuGJx)

Comment: Yes, because there are multiple `<p>` elements which are the first of type with their respective sibling group. `section p:first-of-type` would work fine for what you want though, so you need to explain in your question why that isn't the solution you're looking for instead of saying "any selector combination with `:first-of-type`".

Comment: @nagisa you're welcome. if you look at my answer i solved your issue. cheers.

Comment: The `E:first-of-type` selector looks for any instance where E is the first of its kind among all sibling/adjacent elements.  There are lots of elements that are descendants of `article` in your example, many of which contain paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do what you want without using JavaScript (as shown in your original question). There is currently no global `nth-of-class` selector available. I believe it is because the styles for elements are calculated in one pass. There's no real way for the selectors to be aware of elements in *other* branches of the DOM tree.

Much like how you can use the adjacent sibling (`+`) and general sibling (`~`) combinators to apply styles that come **after** a certain selector, but not before it.

Comment: Hmm, I saw questions where solutions with overriding styles by using `+` and/or `~` are possible, but not so in my case, right? Because, well I can't style `p`s which are children of siblings like that, right? **EDIT** Actually I have an idea how I could style the first element by using overrides with `~`, but then I still can't find a general solution to how to style the last `p`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the first-of-type/last-of type you can select the first/last child of a parent with an element type

```
p:first-of-type
```

or

```
p:last-of-type
```

That will select the first or last paragraph element of that is a child of the parent element

```
p:first-child
```

or

```
p:last-child
```

Similar to last-of-type

W3 schools has some good information on this also

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Linking to w3schools is frowned on around here (see: http://w3fools.com/).  There are plenty of better resources to link to:  MDN (Mozilla Developer Network), http://caniuse.com/, CSS Tricks, etc.

Answer (score -1):

this solve the issue:

```
article section > p:first-child {
    color: red;
}

article > p:last-child{
    color: red;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tdTqD/2/)

or this:

```
main p:first-child {
    color: red;
}

main article > p:last-child{
    color: red;
}
article > ul p{color:black !important;}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tdTqD/3/)

Comment: Last `<p>` will not necessarily will be a bare `article>p` and first `<p>` not necessarily `article>section>p`. In particular any `<p>` element can be under any amount of parents as long as `<p>` is a not-necessarily-direct child of article.

Comment: edited my answer. It would be more useful and productive to know why downvoting my answer BEFORE the OP edit his question. thanks.